# How to batch insert rows into SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

For example, I have a function returns a list of psobject. How to insert the list into SQL in one batch? Or something like bulk insert?

Comment: Have you looked at `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` that you can call from powershell?

Comment: It needs to construct `DataTable` or `DataRow[]` from `PSObject`...

Answer (score 0):

I just posted an article on my blog about using ADOlib, a module (and part of SQLPSX) that wraps a lot of the ADO.NET functionality including SQLBulkCopy.

The post is [here](https://powershellstation.com/2015/09/01/getting-started-with-adolib/)